# Conflicting Event Listeners: Hover, Click, and Click Outside Interaction Issue

Tags: javascript, html

**Question:** I'm working on a web application where I have a profile submenu that should open on hover after 2 seconds, toggle on clicking the profile image, and close when clicking outside the submenu. I'm experiencing a conflict between these event listeners that's preventing them from working together seamlessly.

I have a header section with a profile image that should serve as a trigger for opening and closing a submenu. The submenu is supposed to open on hover after a 2-second delay, toggle when clicking the profile image, and close when clicking outside the submenu area.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
<!-- HTML Code -->
<section class="header">
    <!-- ... Other HTML elements ... -->
    <img src="../img/profile.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" id="profileImg" onclick="toggleMenu()" />
    <!-- ... Submenu HTML ... -->
</section>
```

```
// JavaScript Code
            // PROFILE SUBMENU
            let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");
            let profileImg = document.getElementById("profileImg");

            let submenuTimeout;
            let isSubMenuOpen = false; // Keep track of submenu state

            // Function to open the submenu
            function openSubMenu() {
                subMenu.classList.add("open-menu");
                subMenu.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
                isSubMenuOpen = true;
            }

            // Function to close the submenu
            function closeSubMenu() {
                subMenu.classList.remove("open-menu");
                subMenu.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
                profileImg.style.borderColor = ""; // Reset border
                isSubMenuOpen = false;
            }

            // Toggle the submenu when clicking the profile image
            profileImg.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (isSubMenuOpen) {
                    closeSubMenu();
                } else {
                    openSubMenu();
                }
            });

            profileImg.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                submenuTimeout = setTimeout(openSubMenu, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
            });

            profileImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                clearTimeout(submenuTimeout);
                if (!isSubMenuOpen) {
                    closeSubMenu();
                }
            });

            window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                if (!subMenu.contains(event.target)) {
                    closeSubMenu();
                }
            });
```

I've tried adjusting the order of event listeners, debugging with developer tools, and even separating the hover and click behaviors into distinct functions, but I can't seem to figure out the source of the conflict.

Could someone please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution that allows these event listeners to work together as intended? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Context:**

- I'm using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS for my web application.
- The CSS class **`.open-menu`** controls the visibility of the submenu.
- I'm open to refactoring my code if needed.

Comment: It's not clear what the conflict is that you're experiencing, you should probably create a code pen. Two things i noticed about the code, your "onclick" function , "toggleMenu" doesn't exist it looks like you're handling the logic with the addEventListener.
Also, the last function with the window listener will cause any click on the image to close the submenu, if the image is not part of the sub menu.

Comment: that's duly noted, I'll make things clear and create a pen now to demonstrate the function